# GTK приложения требуют какого-нибудь GTK-фреймворка в системе?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gtkmm3

Пишу приложение под Linux и Windows на C++, используя G++ в роли компилятора и *libgtkmm-3.0-dev*, как библиотеку для UI.

Вопрос заключается в следующем, использует ли GTK какие-нибудь свои *фреймворки*, как некоторые программы используют .NET Framework в Windows?

**Upd.** Если GTK - фреймворк, то нужно ли его отдельно ставить для запуска приложения? То есть встроен ли этот фреймворк в приложение помле компиляции?

Comment: GTK это и есть фреймворк, который используют программы...

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не встроен. По-хорошему, вам надо под все популярные дистрибутивы собрать `deb` или `rpm`, или какие еще бывают пакеты, где указать зависимость от GTK и других запчастей.